# Implementation into HTML a JavaScript auto-dect color function

Tags: javascript, frontend, converters

I would like to implement a JS function that could autodetect an input value and depending on the format of this value it would convert an RGB code to HEX or HEX to RGB. I would like to have an input in HTML with a button and the given value of input would be the argument of my function.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" name="" id="codeColor">
        <button id="button">Calculate colors</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my JS (it does not work) :

```
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let inputCodeColor = document.getElementById('codeColor');


button.addEventListener('click', finalColor);  //on click I would like to do the checkFormat() function that calculates the code color

function finalColor() {
    inputCodeColor.value = checkFormat();
};

function checkFormat() {
    //const regex = /^[A-F0-9]{6}$/g; The regex show me an error so I changed my condition at this moment but ideally I would like to use the regex.

    if ((inputCodeColor.length === 7) || ((inputCodeColor.length === 4) && (inputCodeColor[0] === "#")) || (inputCodeColor.length === 6) || (inputCodeColor.length === 3)){//.match(regex)) { 
//hex to rgb
        inputCodeColor = inputCodeColor.replace("#","");
        let hexColorCode = inputCodeColor.split("");
        //hexColorCode.shift();
        for (let i = 0; i < hexColorCode.length; i++) {
            // check the value of string number
            if (hexColorCode[i] <= 10) {
                hexColorCode[i] = Number(hexColorCode[i])
            }
            switch (hexColorCode[i]) {
                case "a":
                    hexColorCode[i] = 10;
                    break;
                case "b":
                    hexColorCode[i] = 11;
                    break;
                case "c":
                    hexColorCode[i] = 12;
                    break;
                case "d":
                    hexColorCode[i] = 13;
                    break;
                case "e":
                    hexColorCode[i] = 14;
                    break;
                case "f":
                    hexColorCode[i] = 15;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        let red = (16 * hexColorCode[0]) + hexColorCode[1];
        let green = (16 * hexColorCode[2]) + hexColorCode[3];
        let blue = (16 * hexColorCode[4]) + hexColorCode[5];
        const color = [red, green, blue];
        return color; // `Your color in RGB format is (${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`; 
//here I would like to somehow return the hex color and show the code color on site

    } else {//rgb to hex
        let rgbSplittedCode = inputCodeColor.split(",");
        let red = rgbSplittedCode[0];
        let green = rgbSplittedCode[1];
        let blue = rgbSplittedCode[2];

        let r1 = parseInt(red / 16);
        let r2 = red % 16;
        let g1 = parseInt(green / 16);
        let g2 = green % 16;
        let b1 = parseInt(blue / 16);
        let b2 = blue % 16;
        let rgbColorCode = [r1, r2, g1, g2, b1, b2];

        for (let i = 0; i < rgbColorCode.length; i++) {
            if (rgbColorCode[i] < 10) {
                rgbColorCode[i] = rgbColorCode[i].toString();
            }
            switch (rgbColorCode[i]) {
                case 10:
                    rgbColorCode[i] = "A" || "a";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    rgbColorCode[i] = "B" || "b";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    rgbColorCode[i] = "C" || "c";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    rgbColorCode[i] = "D" || "d";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    rgbColorCode[i] = "E" || "e";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    rgbColorCode[i] = "F" || "f";
                    break;
                default:
                    rgbColorCode = parseInt(rgbColorCode[i]);
                    break;
            };
        };

        return rgbColorCode;
//the same return here;
    };

};

checkFormat();
```

If someone knows what I am doing wrong and can help me with my problem, I will really appreciate it.

The result of this code should be shown on the site in as a code color format.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We need a specific description about what happens now, "it doesn't work" isn't enough for us to go on. Include any console errors and a description of the broken behaviour. I will try to help with more detail :)

Comment: I don't have any results on my site after using the live server from VSC. Only I see my HTML elements. Also, the DevTools show no output because I probably implement my doom event incorrectly. But I drown so profoundly in this problem that I can't see what really causes it. I need someone to correct my code.

Comment: At first glance - your if checks are checking the element, not its *value*. Also, you should probably handle cases where hex colour is entered as `#ccc` - still valid, but pressing the button returns `204, NaN, NaN`.